# How to get the last file last file deposited in a gcs bucket (python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to have the last file deposited in a bucket of gcs in python to use it in my dag.
Every day files are deposited in the bucket: gs://name/neth in a format file_yymmdd_.

Answer (score 1):

With Cloud Storage you can only filter by prefix. So, you have the prefix `neth/file_yymmdd_...`, the bucket `name`, you have to get all the files of the prefix that you want and iterate over the metadata to get the latest. No out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you did not have this information tracked somewhere, you can have a crawler on GCS which will iterate the files based on a prefix.
Every time you get the next page of the item you can specify a file as a prefix. Since this is a lexicographic ordered operation eventually after some time you should reach at the last file.
The format you use helps a lot since the combinations are limited (days).

Be aware that when using the list item operations the pages you retrieve list the items stored at that point in time you started the listing of the files (probably behind the scenes BigTable is used for the listing of the files).

This is not blocking you, you can always initiate a new list objects operation based on an offset, thus having something fresh.

Here's a go example that uses the offset

```
storage.Query{Prefix: prefix, StartOffset: offSet}
```